# TLS required but not supported by server

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, motorola-droid-razr

I recently upgraded my phone to ICS and now when I try to access my email I get the error message:
"TLS required but not supported by server"
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Which email app are you using? The default one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out some of the email settings got munged and it was simply a matter of deleting the account info from the phone and then adding it in again.